# Build a custom "social login" provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I wish to build a custom "social login provider" for my spring-boot service.
I wish to let third parties web application and/or mobile application authenticate their users and eventually fetch user related data from my service.

I cannot understand which sprig-boot-security components are necessary.
Can anybody give guidance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was just looking for was is implemented in spring-security-oauth samples https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2

BTW samples can be easily tested using

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth.git
cd spring-security-oauth/samples
mvn package
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/oauth2/sparklr/target/sparklr2-2.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sparklr2.war -v `pwd`/oauth2/tonr/target/tonr2-2.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/tonr2.war  tomcat:alpine
```

- Visit the `sparklr` app in a browser (http://localhost:8080/sparklr2).
- Visit the `tonlr` app in a browser (http://localhost:8080/tonr2)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use Spring Social for social login.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/

Comment: It is quite clear how to use it to authenticate users to my service granting one of the social services. I would like to do the opposite: I would like to let users of another app to grant it in order to load my data in the external app via api.